# Groovy - Strings with "$" replacing it by \$

Tags: groovy

How can i replace a file that contain $ to \$

e.g
dollar file  contains

```
string 1Mcl0c41$
```

after replacing it should look like

```
string 1Mcl0c41\$
```

using sed i can perform

```
$ cat dollar
string 1Mcl0c41$

$ sed "s/1Mcl0c41/1Mcl0c41\\\\/g" dollar > fixed-filename

$ cat fixed-filename
string 1Mcl0c41\$
```

the same i wan't to achieve by using groovy i want to replace all the occurence of $ with \$

Comment: That isn't what you're sed example does...it appends \ onto the end of every occurrence of 1Mcl0c41

Comment: @tim but the output of sed shows me the desired result $ cat dollar
string 1Mcl0c41$

$ sed "s/1Mcl0c41/1Mcl0c41\\\\/g" dollar > fixed-filename

$ cat fixed-filename
string 1Mcl0c41\$

Comment: yeah, but it is not doing it by replacing `$` with `\$`

Comment: @Anish - is my answer acceptable to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a groovy script / program, you can say

```
new File('./fixed-filename') <<  new File('./dollar').text.replace('$','\\$')
```

Or, from the commandline, try

```
groovy -e "line.replace('$','\\\\$')" -p dollars > fixed-filename
```