# Special character escaping

Tags: groovy

All groovy special character #{\'}${"}/', needs to be replaced  by \ in front in a groovy string dynamically

```
input  : anish$spe{cial
output : anish\$spe\{cial
input  : anish}stack{overflow'
output : anish\}stack\{overflow\'
```

I have written a sample program in Java, that i want in groovier way

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.io.*;

/**
 * 
 * @author anish
 *
 */
public class EscapeSpecialChar {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        inputString();
    }
    private static void inputString() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter string to find special characters: ");
        String string = in.readLine();
        // Escape the pattern
        string = escapeRE(string);  
        System.out.println("output: -- " + string);
    }

    // Returns a pattern where all punctuation characters are escaped.
    static Pattern escaper = Pattern.compile("([^a-zA-z0-9])");
    public static String escapeRE(String str) {
        return escaper.matcher(str).replaceAll("\\\\$1");
    }
}
```

Enter string to find special characters: `$Anish(Stack%1231+#$124{}`

output: -- `\$Anish\(Stack\%1231\+\#\$124\{\}`

Comment: so what's your question?

Comment: What have you tried?

Did you look at http://groovy.codehaus.org/Regular+Expressions ?  This is a lot like your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625140/groovy-strings-with-replacing-it-by .   Have you read any Groovy documentation at all?

Comment: @kevincline I tried replace('$','\\$') , this replaces $ with \$, but in my case in a String i have not only $ but also other special character that i need to escape any suggestion doing dynamically, yes it's related to previous question but there i know i have only $ in my Gstring, in this question in my string i have other special characters also

Comment: Why do you need to escape them?  Why is the String `anish}stack{overflow'` Wrong?  It's a perfectly valid String...  Maybe explaning __why__ you need this will help people?

Comment: @tim_yates,i have a utility that convert the binary file to groovy file,let say the converted groovy file having some string like "anish$stack{overflow", the same utility will convert the groovy file to binary file, when it convert it will check whether it's a valid groovy file or not, having these special character will lead to compilation error, that why i need a regex where i can supply any special characyert the program will automatically backslash it

Comment: @anish So you're taking something that isn't groovy (by the very fact that it is in binary form, and contains invalid chars for the groovy compiler), converting this binary data to a String, and then getting the Groovy compiler to compile this non-groovy data to java bytecode?  Can you see where I am getting confused?  Are you basically extracting Strings from a binary file?  If so, why not just get the groovy code to load the Strings itself?  It's another one of your questions where I am hesitant to answer, as I feel there is probably a _much_ better way to do what you are trying to do...

Comment: @tim_yates I have written a sample Java program, the result which i want in groovier style

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This does what your Java code does:

```
System.console().with {
  def inStr = readLine 'Enter string to find special characters: '
  def outStr = inStr.replaceAll( /([^a-zA-Z0-9])/, '\\\\$1' )
  println "Output: $outStr"
}
```

I am still dubious that what I think you are doing is a good idea though... ;-)

Comment: Thanks this is what i want to acheive,

Comment: do let me know how can i escape the space in between we escape the space character, it may confuse , even if “\ “ is equivalent to “ “