# Grails mysql_real_escape_string equivalent

Tags: grails

Is there inbuild funcation in Grails to escape the special character in SQL?  I know prepare is the right command to use, my program already has dynamic sql looking for option to escape the special character.

thanks
SR

Comment: This [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949743/special-character-escapping) would help.

Comment: @sfgroups, are you preparing this SQL string by yourserl, or using Hibernate/GORM?

Comment: I am creating sql myself. since we are using mysql view.

Answer (score 1):

In Grails and modern frameworks consider using HQL instead of SQL.
This article might be useful to you: http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/tag/sql-injection-attack/